# JavaScript - Wait until all array.push() are complete before returning function

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have written a function that loops over an object and uses `array.push(XYZ)` to append the value (`XYZ`) to the array (`array`). After the loop is complete the function returns a promise. When I use `myFunction().then(function(response) { console.log(response[0])})`, I get `undefined` in the console. When I type in `console.log(response[0])` in the console, I get the correct value. What am I doing wrong? I think that it is taking time to push the value into the array but I am not 100%. Any help will be appreciated.

**My Code** *(I have not included the code defining `db` but it is not important as getting the info from the database is working fine.)*

```
function getChild(uid) {
    promise = db.collection("users").doc(uid).get().then(function(doc) {
      output = [];
      val = doc.data();
      studentsObj = val.students;
      studentsObj.forEach(function(student) {
        db.collection("students").doc(student).get().then(function(res) {
          varl = res.data()
          output.push(varl);
        });
      });
      return output;
    });
    return promise;
};

getChild("parentUserID").then(function(reply) {
  got = reply;
  console.log(got);
});
```

Comment: It's not the time to call `push`, its the time to call `db.collection("students").doc(student).get()`. That's asynchronous. You will return the empty output before it returns.

Answer (score 1):

Asynchronous operations inside a `forEach` won't be chained with the outer Promise chain - use `map` instead to create an array of `Promises`, and then you need to return a `Promise.all` so that the promises generated by each `studentsObj` are properly chained. You should also try to avoid implicitly creating global variables - use `const` instead.

Try something like this:

```
const getChild = (uid) => (
  db.collection("users").doc(uid).get()
  .then(doc => {
    const { students } = doc.data();
    return Promise.all(students.map(student => (
      db.collection("students").doc(student).get()
      .then((res) => res.data())
    )))
  })
);
```

Or, using `async` functions instead to make the code a bit flatter:

```
const getChild = async (uid) => {
  const doc = await db.collection("users").doc(uid).get();
  const { students } = doc.data();
  return Promise.all(students.map(async (student) => {
    const res = await db.collection("students").doc(student).get();
    return res.data();
  )));
};
```

Comment: Can this be executed using `getChild("parentUserID")`?

Comment: Yes, calling `getChild` will now return a `Promise` that resolves after all asynchronous operations are done

Comment: If it solved your problem, consider marking the answer as Accepted to indicate that the issue is resolved